# Same docker images have different behavior on different hosts - jersey 1 does not load classes

Tags: docker, jersey, jax-rs, docker-container, docker-image

emphasized textThere is different behavior of the same docker image on different hosts.
On host 1, the classes that belong to rest package, they are initiated successfully by jersey.
On host 2 and 3, the classes of rest package are not initiated.

My *dockerfile* is:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine

COPY ./reasoner-api/target/reasoner-api.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/reasoner-api.war
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

I run the docker as:

> docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -i -t semantic_web:latest

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                io.swagger.jaxrs.json,
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing,
                restapi
            </param-value>
    </servlet>


    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v0.6/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
```

**CASES**

A) **Jersey initiates classes successfully - host 1**

> host 1: OC:Windows 10 pro OC Build 18363.900 64-bit, version 1909

> Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
> **Logs -  successful initiation**

```
15-Jul-2020 07:49:38.566 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  io.swagger.jaxrs.json
  io.swagger.jaxrs.listing
  restapi
15-Jul-2020 07:49:38.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:    
               class restapi.TestService                                                                                                                                                                                             
               class restapi.PropertyService
```

B) **Jersey does not initiate any classes from restapi package -  host 2 and 3**

I tried it on two other different hosts

*host 2:*

> OS: Linux 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC
> 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe

*host 3:*

> Windows 10 Pro, OC build 17763.1039, version 1809

> Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b

**Logs -  no class is initiated from restapi package**

```
14-Jul-2020 12:47:14.634 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  io.swagger.jaxrs.json
  io.swagger.jaxrs.listing
  restapi
14-Jul-2020 12:47:14.676 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/reasoner-api.war has finished in 13,273 ms
```

*com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found* line does not even appear in logs, as in the successful scenario in host 1

When I hit *http://localhost:8080/reasoner-api/v0.6/testReasoner*, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoaderPA()Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;
```

Let me know if I should provide more information for the hosts.